# Remoção de comentários no HTML enviado pelo servidor

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Todos nós conhecemos os bons e velhos comentários HTML:

```
<!-- Oi, eu sou o Goku! -->
```

A questão é: **existe alguma forma de excluir comentários do HTML que o servidor envia para o cliente?** Penso que tal configuração seja feita ao nível do servidor (estou especificamente abaixo do IIS), mas soluções baseadas em programação também são bem-vindas (penso que algo nas rotinas globais: `Global.asa` - para scripts ASP - ou no `Global.asax.cs` - para páginas ASP.NET - seja também adequado).

A necessidade surgiu recentemente na empresa em que trabalho, pois há vários comentários HTML - enviados portanto para o cliente - com detalhes negociais do funcionamento das rotinas, e esses comentários deveriam ter sido feitos com suas respectivas versões `server side`, de forma a serem ignorados durante o processo de build.

Comment: Não creio existir alguma solução da maneira como você imaginou. Na minha opinião a alternativa mais simples seria converter tais comentários em comentários do tipo server-side utilizando por exemplo a opção Find and Replace do Visual Studio.

Comment: @iuristona num primeiro momento pensei nisso também, mas resolvi perguntar assim mesmo! Se for algo que possa ser resolvido pelo servidor, seria uma preocupação a menos na hora de doutrinar a equipe. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela participação

Comment: Mesmo que exista maneira de processar e remover no servidor (um parser de HTML faria isso), acho que não vale a pena onerar todas as requisições com essa filtragem. O ideal seria algum tipo de script que realmente alterasse os arquivos fontes, removendo totalmente os comentários ou convertendo-os para uma versão server-side.

Comment: Bom argumento, @bfavaretto! Não havia pensado sob essa ótica.

Comment: É claro que é possível! Em **PHP**, por exemplo, basta usar a função ``ob_start`` para pegar o conteúdo da página antes de ser enviado e ``preg_replace`` para remover os comentários HTML. Mas em ASP não sei como fazer. Pesquisa aqui: https://www.google.com.br/search?q=asp+ob_start+like

Comment: A sugestão do @bfavaretto é a melhor. Pre-processe todo o seu conteúdo, retirando os comentários. PS: Alguém por favor edite o post. O comentário correto seria `<!-- Oi, eu sou o Goku! -->`.

Comment: @OnoSendai done ;-)

Comment: @TiagoCésarOliveira perfeito, obrigado. =)

Comment: @GabrielSantos concordo contigo, mas também concordo que o ideal seria pré-processar os arquivos para evitar o processamento desnecessário. Já estou aqui trabalhando num regex que me permita trabalhar com um parser a fim de resolver isso. Quando terminar, compartilho aqui a implementação.

Comment: @TiagoCésarOliveira É, mas se você tem muitos arquivos, vai dar um trabalho para fazer isso na mão. Com uma regex, o processo fica automático. Além disso, é possível economizar bandwidth removendo espaços e quebras de linha. Eu sempre faço isso, deixando o HTML em uma só linha. Você que sabe.

Comment: @GabrielSantos o que estou tentando fazer é um executável que lê arquivo a arquivo, localiza os comentários via regex e os transforma em comentários server side. Dessa forma economizo o pré-processamento antes de servir a página

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Para os arquivos de código HTML

No caso de usar Asp.NET Utilize os **comentários próprios do Asp.Net** e eles não aparecerão no HTML.

```
<%-- É de mais de 8000!!!  --%>
```

### Para os arquivos JS

Utilizo este script para concatenar e minificar todos os scripts da minha aplicação.
Maiores detalhes sobre a DLL vc encontra em : https://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/

```
        Response.ContentType = "application/x-javascript";
        string debug = Request.QueryString["debug"];
        string TakeScript = Request.QueryString["take"];

        List<string> JsFiles = new List<string>();

        JsFiles.Add("jquery-1.8.0.js");
        JsFiles.Add("jquery-ui.js");
        JsFiles.Add("meuScript.js");

        StringBuilder Output = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var JsFile in JsFiles)
        {
            foreach (var JsLine in File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("jsfiles/" + JsFile)))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(JsLine.Replace(" ", string.Empty)))
                    Output.Append(JsLine + "\n");
            }
        }

        if (debug == "true")
        {
            Response.Write(Output.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            CodeSettings Settings = new CodeSettings();
            Settings.MinifyCode = true;
            Settings.OutputMode = OutputMode.SingleLine;
            Minifier AjaxMinifier = new Minifier();
            string CompressedJavascript = AjaxMinifier.MinifyJavaScript(Output.ToString(), Settings);
            Response.Write(CompressedJavascript);
        }
```

Comment: Perfeito para soluções ASP.NET, porém ignora arquivos de suporte (js, css). É necessário também trocar o final da tag, de `-->` para `--%>`.

Comment: @OnoSendai Para esses eu recomendo utilizar a DLL encontrada em: https://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/. Utilizo ela no site da minha empresa, concateno todos os scripts e faço a minificação.

Comment: solução interessante, executada a cada successful build? A um tempo atrás eu implementei um HTTP Module que realizava o mesmo trabalho e cacheava os resultados.

Answer (score 1):

A solução que eu acho que você poderia implementar seria *minificar* o seu HTML. Dessa forma, você "prepara" o seu HTML para as requisições vindas do cliente limpando espaços extras, removendo quebras de linhas (isso só não é feito dentro dos blocos JavaScript) e, é claro, removendo comentários.

Claro que isso depende muito da arquitetura da sua aplicação. Esse tipo de rotina é bastante comum quando o HTML consiste em arquivos de templates nos quais as variáveis serão incorporadas a *placeholders* e, após isso, pode haver a rotina de minificação a qual falei.

Apenas um detalhe: você pode fazer isso com arquivos CSS e JS também. O carregamento do seu site ficará consideravelmente mais rápido :)

Comment: Infelizmente não é possível fazer isso porque as páginas precisam de pré-processamento (no caso dos scripts ASP)...